# How can I use a Linq expression using reflection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, entity-framework

I currently have a situation where I'm performing a search using Linq to Entities.

If I want to search by a client's Reference code, I'll use this method: `GetClientByReference("A01")`

```
public IQueryable<DataLayer.Client> GetClientByReference(String reference)
{
    return new DataLayer.DlClient(this.Entities).GetClientByReference(reference);
}
```

If I want to search by an client's name, I'll use this method: `GetClientByName("Joe")`

```
public IQueryable<DataLayer.Client> GetClientByName(String name)
{
    return new DataLayer.DlClient(this.Entities).GetClientByName(name);
}
```

Obviously, with regards to scalability, this is pretty awful, because I would need to combine methods together, and write one for each searchable field (`GetClientByDateAndReferenceAndName`??) Is there any way to make this more generic?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like:

- `GetClient("Reference", "A01")`
- `GetClient("Name", "Joe")`
- `GetClient("Reference", "A01", "Name", "Joe")`

Comment: How dit you solve it? Did you use `Expression<Func<Client, bool>>` or would the suggested `Func<Client, bool>` work also without internally returning all of the clients instead of the asked one?

Comment: I used the answer "as-is", using `Func<Client, bool> filter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your `DataLayer.DlClient(this.Entities)` return `IQueryable<Client>`:

```
public IQueryable<DataLayer.Client> GetClientBy(Expression<Func<Client, bool>> filter)
{
    return new DataLayer.DlClient(this.Entities).Where(filter);
}
```

now you can

```
var clients = GetClientBy(client => client.Name == "Joe");

var clients = GetClientBy(client => client.Reference == "A01");

var clients = GetClientBy(client => client.Reference == "A01" &&  
                                    client.Name == "Joe");
```

Comment: Question: In LinqToSql I would change `Func<Client, bool>` to `Expression<Func<Client, bool>>` because the first one would result in a query of all clients and filter it in memory, while the second one converts well to sql. Is this not true in your situation?

Comment: This is pretty good :) and with some mangling I managed to adapt it to my use case.